# Create a login page which redirects to a specific page?

Tags: login

I know you are able to redirect users from the regular login page. But I don't want to do this. I want to keep the standard login intact and create another login page which when the user logs in from they are redirected to a specific page.

Is this doable?

It is in a Wordpress Multisite network and I want this function for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to customize this alternative login screen but this should do the work for the redirection :

- create a template for your custom loginpage like 'custom-login.php'
- add `<?php wp_login_form( array('redirect' => 'your_sanitize_custom_url ') ); ?>`
- done !

Comment: What I am looking for is a global page, like domain.com/customlogin which the user who has a site in the Multisite network visits and it will then take the user to domain.com/user1/custompage. I think I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Or can you make the standard login form redirect to a specific page if the user visits the login page with another custom url?